# List of values to Columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in which one of the column has the list of values ( each values is a value of a feature). Now I need to convert those list of values into each column.
Ex:  DataFrame is having two columns in which data column is list of values

> ```
>    data  ,  Time      
> [1,2,3,4], 12:34   
> [5,6,7,8], 12:36   
> [9,1,2,3], 12:45
> ```

I need to convert then as

Ex:

```
   data0 data1 data2 data3 Time
    1   ,  2  ,  3  ,  4  , 12:34    
    5   ,  6  ,  7  ,  8  , 12:36    
    9   ,  1  ,  2  ,  3  , 12:45
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame` constructor with converting column `data` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) + [`tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html), [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) column `Time`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['data'].values.tolist()).add_prefix('data').join(df['Time'])
print (df)
   data0  data1  data2  data3   Time
0      1      2      3      4  12:34
1      5      6      7      8  12:36
2      9      1      2      3  12:45
```

Answer (score 10):

***`numpy`***
*We get a very fast solution by using `np.column_stack` directly on values.  The only thing left to do is to stitch together the columns*

```
v = np.column_stack([df.data.values.tolist(), df.Time.values])
c = ['data{}'.format(i) for i in range(v.shape[1] - 1)] + ['Time']
pd.DataFrame(v, df.index, c)

  data0 data1 data2 data3   Time
0     1     2     3     4  12:34
1     5     6     7     8  12:36
2     9     1     2     3  12:45
```

---

***timeit***

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(df['data'].values.tolist()).add_prefix('data').join(df['Time'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 ms per loop

%%timeit
v = np.column_stack([df.data.values.tolist(), df.Time.values])
c = ['data{}'.format(i) for i in range(v.shape[1] - 1)] + ['Time']
pd.DataFrame(v, df.index, c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 183 µs per loop
```